# Como desserializar uma lista com itens do tipo { "chave": "valor" }?

Tags: java, json, gson, desserialização

Preciso deserializar um JSON, mas não consigo mapear o objeto enumerado.

Segue o JSON:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "1": "Bola"
    },
    {
      "2": "Quadrado"
    },
    {
      "3": "Retangulo"
    }
  ],
  "code": 0,
  "success": true
}
```

O meu domínio esta mapeado da seguinte forma, ate o momento:

```
public class Objeto {

    @SerializedName(value="list")
    public List<objClass> objList;

    public void setObj(List<objClass> month) {
        this.objList = month;
    }

    public class objClass {

        //Aqui eu deveria mapear o objeto com a cheve numerica

    }
}
```

Comment: Olá, terias como clarificar um pouco mais ela?

Comment: Utilize sua ferramenta online http://cleancss.com/json-editor/ ou http://jsonlint.com/ são muito útil, se não esta achando o chave, sua estrutura este `[ ]` é chave.

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples é declarar o tipo que vai receber a lista como `List<Map<String, String>>`. Isto porque o *GSon* considera a notação `"chave": "valor"` como uma entrada em um *LinkedTreeMap*.

```
public class Tipo{

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List<Map<String, String>> lista;
    private int code;
    private boolean success;

    //getters
}
```

Será, no entanto, "mais correcto" ter uma classe, outra que não *LinkedTreeMap*, para representar cada valor `"chave": "valor"`.

A forma de o conseguir é recorrer a um *custom deserializer*.

Primeiro a classe que vai receber o resultado da desserialização:

```
public class Tipo{

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List<ListEntry> lista;
    private int code;
    private boolean success;

    //getters

}
```

O conteúdo da lista, ou seja, cada um dos valores `"chave": "valor"`, será representado pela classe *ListEntry*:

```
class ListEntry {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ListEntry(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    //getters

}
```

O *custom deserializer*:

```
private class ListEntryDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ListEntry> {
    @Override
    public ListEntry deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> ite = json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();

        Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = ite.next();
        return new ListEntry(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getAsString());
    }
}
```

Use assim:

```
String jsonString = "{'list': [ {'1':'Bola' }, {'2': 'Quadrado' }, {'3': 'Retangulo' }], 'code': 0, 'success': true}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ListEntry.class, new ListEntryDeserializer()).create();
Tipo tipo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Tipo.class);
```